# Unity Game build gradle to real device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am making a game for Android Mobile Platform using Unity. It is my first time. I installed unity Remote smoothly to my phone. But When I try to run my game in my real device it gives me error message. Message is:Gradle failed. How can I fix it? You can see the error message.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I clicked on Editor to build and run button. (my real device is connected to unity.)
It shows me this message on my console.

Comment: Your project is targeting android-33 but you do not have that part of the Android sdk installed. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html and search for "Setting the Android SDK Target API" for instructions on how to download what you need or change the setting to something you have installed.

Comment: Why my app needs just like high sdk number. Should İ use lower sdk number ? 33  is too more. ( Also , you should now that it is my first project on unity )

Comment: Yes you can select lower Target API by going in 
File -> Build Settings -> Player Settings -> Other Settings > Target API Level 
set the target API level to 30 or 29

Comment: I selected lower Target API. This time gives me this message: "Failed to update Android SDK package list. See the Console for details."  Console log: location of your Java installation. CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to update Android SDK package list.
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat --list  Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 48 seconds (47518 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 7 errors

Comment: It sounds like your Android SDK installation is not correct. I'd install it again and this time add API 33. You'll need it if you ever want to upload to Google Play.

Comment: I solved my problem. And I have different problem. My problem is about Google Admob Package. İs not about SDK. ( I already thought that I am Android Java Developer. ) The solutions of the this question is : Down your SDK version lower than 33. My suggesting is version 30 SDK.